# Spring Boot bootJar failing to run because of embedded Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, vaadin

When creating a fatJar with spring boot, it seems to fail because of the embedded tomcat bean failing to be initialized. I'm using Vaadin 12 with Spring Boot and it still seems to have the issue. I also made sure that no other process is using the port in IntelliJ and also tried running with administrative privileges and it still has the same result.

Log when running jar file:

```
C:\Users\forne\Desktop>java -jar passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::

2019-02-20 21:23:41.094  INFO 1888 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Starting application on LEO-DESKTOP with PID 1888 (started by forne in C:\Users\forne\Desktop)
2019-02-20 21:23:41.105  INFO 1888 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-02-20 21:23:42.165  INFO 1888 --- [           main] o.s.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils      : Failed to introspect annotations on class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.EmbeddedWebServerFactoryCustomizerAutoConfiguration$JettyWebServerFactoryCustomizerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7846e955: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
2019-02-20 21:23:42.165  WARN 1888 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatServletWebServerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.EmbeddedWebServerFactoryCustomizerAutoConfiguration$JettyWebServerFactoryCustomizerConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
2019-02-20 21:23:42.171  INFO 1888 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-02-20 21:23:42.179 ERROR 1888 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatServletWebServerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.EmbeddedWebServerFactoryCustomizerAutoConfiguration$JettyWebServerFactoryCustomizerConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:157) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at tk.leoforney.passcheckerserver.Main.main(Main.java:25) [classes!/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatServletWebServerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.EmbeddedWebServerFactoryCustomizerAutoConfiguration$JettyWebServerFactoryCustomizerConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:584) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:216) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:180) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:154) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.EmbeddedWebServerFactoryCustomizerAutoConfiguration$JettyWebServerFactoryCustomizerConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:584) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:392) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.getWebServerFactoryCustomizerBeans(WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:94) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.getCustomizers(WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:84) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:75) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:61) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:419) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1737) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
        at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.annotationData(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.annotationData(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement.isAnnotationPresent(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.isAnnotationPresent(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.hasAnnotation(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:599) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.annotation.AnnotationClassFilter.matches(AnnotationClassFilter.java:65) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:225) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:288) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:269) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.AbstractAdvisingBeanPostProcessor.isEligible(AbstractAdvisingBeanPostProcessor.java:133) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.AbstractAdvisingBeanPostProcessor.isEligible(AbstractAdvisingBeanPostProcessor.java:115) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractBeanFactoryAwareAdvisingPostProcessor.isEligible(AbstractBeanFactoryAwareAdvisingPostProcessor.java:70) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.AbstractAdvisingBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAdvisingBeanPostProcessor.java:85) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:434) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1749) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) ~[passcheckerserver-0.5-ALPHA.jar:na]
        ... 46 common frames omitted
```

Build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.jaredsburrows:gradle-license-plugin:0.8.42'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.devsoap.vaadin-flow' version '1.0.0.RC8'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.1.RELEASE'
}

vaadin.autoconfigure()

group 'tk.leoforney'
version '0.5-ALPHA'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'com.jaredsburrows.license'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "http://www.javaxt.com/maven"}
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    implementation "com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.7.2"
    implementation "org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.21.0"
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.4"
    implementation "com.vaadin:vaadin-app-layout-flow:1.0.3"
    implementation "commons-codec:commons-codec:1.11"
    implementation "javaxt:javaxt-core:1.9.0"
    implementation "org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:3.10.1"
    compile ('org.vaadin.marcus:shortcut:0.3.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-simple'
    }
}

bootWar {
    vaadin.productionMode=false
    vaadin.submitStatistics=false
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { (it.isDirectory() && it.name != "PassChecker.db") ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}

bootJar {
    vaadin.productionMode=false
    vaadin.submitStatistics=false
    System.out.println("BootJar reached")
    manifest {
        attributes ( 'Start-Class': 'tk.leoforney.passcheckerserver.Main',
                'Version': version,
                'Main-Class': 'org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher')
    }
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect {
            System.out.println(it.getAbsoluteFile().toPath().toString())
            (it.isDirectory() && it.name != "PassChecker.db") ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
}

def getGitHash = { ->
    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine 'git', 'rev-parse', '--short', 'HEAD'
        standardOutput = stdout
    }
    return stdout.toString().trim()
}

task createProperties {
    doLast {
        System.out.println("$projectDir")
        def propFile = new File("$projectDir/out/production/resources/version.properties")
        propFile.createNewFile()
        propFile.withWriter { w ->
            Properties p = new Properties()
            p['version'] = project.version.toString()
            p['vaadin'] = vaadin.version
            p['productionMode'] = vaadin.productionMode.toString()
            p['time'] = new Date().format('MM/dd/yyyy - HH:mm:ss')
            p['hash'] = getGitHash()
            p.store w, null
        }
    }
}

classes {
    dependsOn createProperties
    System.out.println("Property file created")
}
```

Main class:

```
package tk.leoforney.passcheckerserver;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

import java.io.File;

/**
 * Created by Leo on 4/30/2018.
 */
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration.class})
@ServletComponentScan
@EntityScan
public class Main {

    public static String wd = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "Desktop" + File.separator + "PassCheckerServer";
    public static ConfigurableApplicationContext context;
    public static String[] arguments;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runner runner = new Runner(args);
        context = SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
        arguments = args;
        try {
            runner.run();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Exited Runner");
        System.exit(1);
    }

}
```